# Cordova install app on Android but do not start it

Tags: android, cordova

Is there a command to install a Cordova app onto an Android device but prevent the app from starting when the installation is finished?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by using an [adb-server](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html) and some commands:

First, you have to run:

```
cordova build android
```

or if you use ionic:

```
ionic build android
```

This command creates an *.apk file(lets call it: this_is_your_apk_file.apk) in your *\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk* project-directory.

Then you have to go into this directory:

```
cd path_to_your_project\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk

adb install this_is_your_apk_file.apk
```

You may have to wait until your device is ready for communicating with the adb-server, but as soon as your device is shown in the device-list by using this command:

```
adb devices
```

the commands above should work as described.